# How to get return value of JavaScript function in a hidden field while loading a page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function in javascript.  While loading an HTML page, I would like to store the JavaScript function's value in a hidden field.

Suppose I have:

```
function add()
{
  return 10;
}
```

Then this 10 should be stored in a text field while loading the page:

```
<input type='hidden' name='anything'/>
```

Comment: And you're stuck at what point?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElement('[name=anything]').value = add();

function add(){
    return 10;
}
​
```

You can add first line in a function and call that function on `onload` of body tag.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jss3Y/

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function in this manner

```
function add(){
   var answer = 10; //or any calculation you want to do.
   var hiddenField =  "<input type='hidden' name='anything' value='"+ answer +"'/>"
   var myForm = document.getElementById('myFormID');
   // var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]; alternate for selecting form
   myForm.appendChild(hiddenField)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an id for your input like this :

```
<input id="hidden_input" type='hidden' name='anything' value=""/>
```

them you can do this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

document.getElementById("hidden_input").value=add();

function add(){
    return 10;
}
</script>
```